# Gettime is returning wrong date when called by Calendar object

Tags: java

I instantiate a GregorianCalendar and then set the time and dates.its showing perfectly okay when I display the `Calendar` Object but when I store it in Date variable by calling `getTime()` and display date variable, the date shown is somehow increased by 1 month. please help. the below code shows date as **2014-01-20**

```
Calendar c=new GregorianCalendar();
    c.set(2013, 12, 20);
    Date d=c.getTime();
    System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: Please tell me: How can anyone guess what you could be doing wrong without seeing your code? Seriously.

Comment: its showing date as 2014-01-20. can you tell me now?

Comment: Thank you for the code finally. Months are 0 based, and so use the constants that are part of the Calendar class. In the future, please ask a better more complete question. Note that this is a common question, one that you should have found through searching before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Months are 0 based, so don't use numbers for months but rather the Calendar constants.

i.e.,

```
c.set(2013, Month.DECEMBER, 20);
```